# Running Hadoop MR jobs without Admin privilege on Windows

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have installed Hadoop 2.3.0 in windows and able to execute MR jobs successfully. But when I trying to execute MR jobs in normal privilege (without admin privilege) means job get fails with following exception. Here I tried with Pig Script sample.

```
    2014-10-15 12:02:32,822 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:kaveen (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Split class org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit not found
2014-10-15 12:02:32,823 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.io.IOException: Split class org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1794)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:360)
    ... 7 more

2014-10-15 12:02:32,827 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
2014-10-15 12:02:32,827 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Output Path is null in abortTask()
```

Update:

I was able to drill down the problem and found that the exception raised in the following line at method "MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:363)".

```
private <T> T getSplitDetails(Path file, long offset) 
  throws IOException {
   FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
   FSDataInputStream inFile = fs.open(file);
   inFile.seek(offset);
   String className = StringInterner.weakIntern(Text.readString(inFile));
   Class<T> cls;
   try {
     cls = (Class<T>) conf.getClassByName(className);
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
     IOException wrap = new IOException("Split class " + className + 
                                         " not found");
     wrap.initCause(ce);

     throw wrap;
   }
```

But If I start "NodeManager" with admin privilege mean the above exception won't occur. I don't know why MR job not working when I start "NodeManager" with normal privilege.

If anyone know the reason and solution for above problem. Please guide me as soon as possible.

Comment: I tried below possibilities also but this issue not fix.                                                                 (1) I set full permission for "tmp" and "logs" folder as like below 
c:\>cacls C:\tmp /E /T /G <nm account>:F
c:\>cacls C:\Syncfusion\BigDataSDK\1.1.0.8\SDK\Hadoop\logs/E /T /G <nm account>:F

(2) I set full permission for (.staging) dircetory in hdfs location.
( hadoop dfs -chmod -R 777 <file-name>).

(3) I also tried to change owner and group which contain full perivilege in my case 
"hadoop dfs -chgrp -R Administrators / "
"hadoop dfs -chown -R <ownername> / "

Comment: Anyone please guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: Could be a classpath permissions issue...?  Have you tried making sure the pig jar(s) are in the non-privileged users classpath and that they are accessable?  I do not know Pig very well, nor have I ever run Hadoop in Windows... but the error certainly seems to indicate an inability to find pig jar(s).

Comment: Hi @John Galt, Thanks for your kind information. I added all classpath correctly. Even I run wordcount.jar file I got error at **org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs()**. **Error for running jarFile** [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600916/how-to-run-mr-job-in-normal-privilege)   Please help me where I made a mistake while configuring.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the location of tmp directory location for hadoop using the below property

```
<property>
   <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
   <value>/other/tmp</value>
</property>
```

Your default tmp location is c:\tmp which requires admin privilege to access. Change the location into any sub directory and try MR job without admin privilege.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @kumar, Thanks for update. Its working fine. You said that the problem might be permission is not available at 'C:\tmp' location. Even I gave full permission for folder and sub-folder of 'C:\tmp' but it doesn't work. will you elaborate the reason for this?

Comment: My solution is the easiest way to resolve the problem. You can give full permission to everyone for the /tmp directory. Then it will work without changing the default location.