# How to run MR job in Normal privilege

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2

I have installed Hadoop 2.3.0 and able to execute MR jobs successfully. But when I trying to execute MR jobs in normal privilege (without admin privilege) means job get fails with following exception. 
I tried "WordCount.jar" sample.

```
14/10/28 09:16:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1414467725299_0002_r_000
000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.getFsStatistics(Task.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.<init>(Re
duceTask.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:414
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

By debugging the source I drill down the problem occurs at class YarnChild.java

```
childUGI.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object run() throws Exception {
                    // use job-specified working directory
                    FileSystem.get(job).setWorkingDirectory(job.getWorkingDirectory());
                    taskFinal.run(job, umbilical); // run the task
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

But If I start "NodeManager" with admin privilege mean the above exception won't occur. I don't know why MR job not working when I start "NodeManager" with normal privilege.

If anyone know the reason and solution for above problem. Please do me the favor as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you running in Windows or some Linux environment? What Hadoop version?

Comment: Hi @Lauri, Thank for response. I have installed Hadoop 2.3.0 on Windows8..

Comment: While running Pig Script also I got error as in this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291912/running-hadoop-mr-jobs-without-admin-privilege-on-windows)

Comment: Did you compile it from sources on your computer? Sorry, don't know anything about Pig.

Comment: Yes, I compiled it from sources using maven. When I start **Nodemanager** in **cmd** prompt with admin privilege mean MR job working perfectly.

Comment: I have personally fought many wars with Hadoop under Windows, and mostly lost. It only "kinda" works. I wouldn't be very surprised if it requires admin privileges to run correctly, but unfortunately I can't point out any documentation about this for you.

Comment: Some of the properties are assigned in **job.xml** file and this file are added with _**JobConf.addResource(“job.xml”)**_ at **YarnChild.java**. But I found that some of the properties such as “mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir” is not assigned at job.xml while running in normal privilege (not in admin cmd). Do you know where the properties are supplied to **job.xml**? and also Do you know where the **job.xml** found in local filesystem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63844/discussion-between-ave-rja-and-lauri-peltonen).